# Jwt Unable to valid issuer or audience

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt

This is my token decoder. When I try to decode it, my principal ends up being null thus leading to this error:

> 'IDX10208: Unable to validate audience.
>   validationParameters.ValidAudience is null or whitespace and
>   validationParameters.ValidAudiences is null.'

When I decode my token to check

> "nbf": 1539167980,   "exp": 1539168580,   "iat": 1539167980,   "iss":
>   "http://localhost:55260",   "aud": "http://localhost:55260"

This is the host that my token generator runs on as well. Why is the principal causing issues?

```
public class DecodeToken
{
    private IConfiguration configuration;
    public DecodeToken(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public AuthenticationDto Decode(String Input)
    {
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JwtAuthentication:SecurityKey"]));
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var tokenSecure = handler.ReadToken(Input) as SecurityToken;
        var validations = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = key,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = false
        };
        SecurityToken securityToken;
        var principal = handler.ValidateToken(Input, validations, out securityToken);
        var jwtSecurityToken = securityToken as JwtSecurityToken;
        if (jwtSecurityToken == null || !jwtSecurityToken.Header.Alg.Equals(SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenException("Invalid Token");
        }
        AuthenticationDto authenticationDto = new AuthenticationDto
        {
            Email = principal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "Email").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault(),
            UserName = principal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "UserName").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault(),
            FirstName = principal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "FirstName").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault(),
            LastName = principal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "LastName").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault(),
            PhoneNumber = principal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "PhoneNumber").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault(),
            Id = principal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "Id").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault(),
            ExpiryDateTime = principal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "exp").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault(),
            Roles = principal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "Roles").Select(c => c.Value).ToList(),
        };
        return authenticationDto;
    }
}
```

This is what my Startup.cs looks like:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Jwt";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Jwt";
})
.AddJwtBearer("Jwt", options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtAuthentication:SecurityKey"])),

        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtAuthentication:Issuer"],

        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtAuthentication:Audience"],

        ValidateLifetime = true, //validate the expiration and not before values in the token

        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero //5 minute tolerance for the expiration date
    };
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
            if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "true");
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```

Have I configured something wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your error appears to make perfect sense. In `ConfigureServices`, you're setting up the `TokenValidationParameters` so that it validates your issuer/audience and you're providing values for `ValidIssuer` and `ValidAudience`, but you're *not doing the same* in your `Decode` function, where you're only setting `ValidateIssuer` and `ValidateAudience` without setting the values that you expect. You need to configure these on your `validations` variable in `Decode`, like this:

```
var validations = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = key,
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidateLifetime = false,
    // Add these...
    ValidIssuer = configuration["JwtAuthentication:Issuer"],
    ValidAudience = configuration["JwtAuthentication:Audience"]
};
```